# Is there any sort of precedent for training to learn / being taught Feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, training

I'm interested in acquiring a specific Feat more quickly that just from levelling. It's a Mastery Feat for the weapon I've just portentously received and am proficient with, but would like to become excellent with.

I know that you can gain proficiencies in entire weapons classes as "training", but that's not quite the same as learning a Feat.

Is there an established process for stuff like this? Naturally, I'm going to talk to my DM about it, but I'm curious to know whether there's any precedent for it.

Some specifics:

- Character: Half-Orc Barbarian.
- Weapon: Spear. (With bonus flavour stuff, but mechanically just a spear most of the time)
- Feat: Either Polearm Master (errata'd to include Spears) or Spear Mastery (from UA)

Comment: Is the feat you are talking about weapon mastery? Be aware that that feat only gives proficiency with some weapons, and does not make you a master

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Details added. Half-Orc Barbarian. Spear. Polearm Master / Spear Mastery.

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame details added. See above.

Comment: Related: [Are there any Feats for / ways to use spears that reflect its dominance over shorter melee weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/181589)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov did you already spot that that one was mine too? ;)

Comment: @Brondahl I did, I linked because it gives further context to your question here.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for the green check?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### In the *Dungeon Master's Guide* chapter 7.

The section ["Marks of Prestige"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/other-rewards#MarksofPrestige) suggests training to gain a feat as a potential reward for completing a great quest:

> A character might be offered special training in lieu of a financial reward. This kind of training isn’t widely available and thus is highly desirable. It presumes the existence of a skilled trainer — perhaps a retired adventurer or champion who is willing to serve as a mentor. The trainer might be a reclusive wizard or haughty sorcerer who owes the queen a favor, the knight-commander of the King’s Guard, the leader of a powerful druid circle, a quirky monk who lives in a remote mountaintop pagoda, a barbarian chieftain, a warlock living among nomads as a fortune-teller, or an absentminded bard whose plays and poetry are known throughout the land.
>
> A character who agrees to training as a reward must spend downtime with the trainer (see chapter 6 for more information on downtime activities). In exchange, the character is guaranteed to receive a special benefit. Possible training benefits include the following:
>
> - The character gains inspiration daily at dawn for 1d4 + 6 days.
> - The character gains proficiency in a skill.
> - **The character gains a feat.**

The guidance given suggests that this sort of reward be reserved for completion of quests that bring the characters some measure of prestige throughout the region or realm, hence "Marks of Prestige". Obviously this is entirely up to the DM. Aside from taking a feat with your ASI, there are no player-facing choices for taking feats.

Comment: So you're saying there's a chance?

Comment: If you ask the DM nicely.